# What props can be passed to Navigator.push

Tags: ios, reactjs, navigation, react-native, navigator

I've been searching for about an hour now with 0 results to this question. I'm just looking for a list of the props that can be used when calling `navigator.push`, specifically how I can use the `sceneConfig` prop in the call, but a whole list would be really helpful. Of course like always Facebooks documentation is only half baked and quite vague.

What do I pass to `navigator.push`? I need all the keys and values for the object that could be passed into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `Navigator.push`, you can provide an argument that is an object with any number of keys and values. The navigator doesn't actually use the values in this for anything, it just gets passed along to your callbacks, `renderScene` and `configureScene`.

The prop `renderScene` gets the object you called `push` with, allowing you to examine its contents and return the view you'd like to render.

The prop `configureScene` gets the object you called `push` with, along with the other routes on the stack (the `initialRoute` prop, and any other objects you previously called `push` with and haven't popped). Here, you can return something from `Navigator.SceneConfigs` to describe how the route should animate

Comment: Thanks for responding but did you even read my question? I need to know what I can pass into the `push` function not how Navigator works. There is plenty of documentation on how it works, there just is no documentation on how to actually use it in depth.

Comment: @RyanWilson I did read the question, and I'm trying to answer it. What you can pass into the push function is: *anything*. It takes an object. There are no special keys. Navigator does not expect any other parameters for the `push` function. You just pass an object with whatever data you want to use for the Navigator to know what to render. The `sceneConfig` prop you're asking about does not exist. There is a `configureScene` prop, which I described in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

like this you can pass

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: "NextPage",
    component: NextPage,
    passProps: {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password},
});
```

and in NextPage you can get using this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: this.props.username,
        password: this.props.password
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass properties to the next scene or are your trying to set different transitions between scenes?

If its the former you just pass an object into navigator.push and you can access the values from navigator.state.routeStack which will give you an array of all your current routes and the name and whatever other properties you passed into the push object.

If you're trying to set different transitions between scenes then I think you have to go to wherever you're using  and inside configureScene={route, routeStack) => } you should be able to give options like if (route.name === 'Welcome') { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}

Not sure if this was exactly what you were looking for!

Comment: If you're just asking about how to navigate, you would just pass the name of the next route in the push statement : navigator.push({name: "Login Page"}); and in the renderScene you would say if (route.name) { return <WhateverComponent />}